# Inverting MQL queries

Tags: json, freebase, mql

[Chapter 3 of the MQL reference](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch03) (specifically section 3.2.6) talks about inverting queries to obtain the same data in a different structure, either to simplify the query or massage the data to return a structure that's similar to your own.

So I start with the following query:

```
https://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?query={"query":{"type":"/automotive/model","name":"Ford Taurus","generations":[]}}
```

Readable version:

```
{
    "type":"/automotive/model",
    "name":"Ford Taurus",
    "generations":[]
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "code": "/api/status/ok",
  "result": {
    "generations": [
      "First Generation Ford Taurus",
      "Second Generation Ford Taurus",
      "Fifth Generation Ford Taurus",
      "Sixth Generation Ford Taurus",
      "Fourth Generation Ford Taurus",
      "Third Generation Ford Taurus"
    ],
    "name": "Ford Taurus",
    "type": "/automotive/model"
  },
  "status": "200 OK",
  "transaction_id": "cache;cache04.p01.sjc1:8101;2013-04-25T22:05:58Z;0012"
}
```

But I want to make the query generation-centric, so I modify it like so:

```
https://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?query={"query":[{"type":"/automotive/generation","model":"Ford Taurus","name":null}]}
```

Readable version:

```
[{
    "type":"/automotive/generation",
    "model":"Ford Taurus",
    "name":null
}]
```

Results:

```
{
  "code": "/api/status/ok",
  "result": [
    {
      "model": "Ford Taurus",
      "name": "First Generation Ford Taurus",
      "type": "/automotive/generation"
    },
    {
      "model": "Ford Taurus",
      "name": "Third Generation Ford Taurus",
      "type": "/automotive/generation"
    }
  ],
  "status": "200 OK",
  "transaction_id": "cache;cache01.p01.sjc1:8101;2013-04-25T23:00:35Z;0010"
}
```

My inverted query only returns two generations! Please help me figure out why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Freebase schema page for [Automobile Generation](https://www.freebase.com/automotive/generation?schema) you'll see that the `model` property has been deprecated and replaced by a **models** property. Making that change to your query:

```
[{
  "type": "/automotive/generation",
  "models": "Ford Taurus",
  "name": null
}]
```

Gives you the expected result set:

```
[
  {
    "models": "Ford Taurus",
    "name": "First Generation Ford Taurus",
    "type": "/automotive/generation"
  },
  {
    "models": "Ford Taurus",
    "name": "Second Generation Ford Taurus",
    "type": "/automotive/generation"
  },
  {
    "models": "Ford Taurus",
    "name": "Fifth Generation Ford Taurus",
    "type": "/automotive/generation"
  },
  {
    "models": "Ford Taurus",
    "name": "Sixth Generation Ford Taurus",
    "type": "/automotive/generation"
  },
  {
    "models": "Ford Taurus",
    "name": "Fourth Generation Ford Taurus",
    "type": "/automotive/generation"
  },
  {
    "models": "Ford Taurus",
    "name": "Third Generation Ford Taurus",
    "type": "/automotive/generation"
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow! I made it singular by accident (I was looking at the *models* schema so I didn't know about *model*). Thanks!